# How to keep original names of files in destination when moving them using data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to keep the names of original files when moving them, from say Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data Lake in Azure Data Factory? Currently they are being renamed by Azure to completely something meaningless

Answer (score 6):

This is supported. Specify "copyBehavior" as "PreserveHierarchy" in your ADLS sink in copy activity. You will find the same config in the copy wizard as well. Check documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector#copy-activity-properties

Comment: No. looks like name changing is by design: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector#example-copy-data-from-azure-blob-to-azure-data-lake-store . "When fileName is not specified, Copy includes all files in the folderPath for input dataset. When fileName is not specified for an output dataset, the name of the generated file would be in the following this format: Data..txt (for example: : Data.0a405f8a-93ff-4c6f-b3be-f69616f1df7a.txt" . It would make sense to preserve old filenames, but oh well.. Only options is a copy activity per file :(

Comment: We will improve the documentation to avoid such confusion. The way i shared would actually work. Check this link with more detailed explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-blob-connector#recursive-and-copybehavior-examples. And to do binary copy (copy files as-is from source to destination), you can specify the folderPath and skip the file format setting in both input and output dataset config.

Comment: @LindaWang-MSFT that link is not working. Can you repost if its updates?

Answer (score 0):

The file name attribute for the output dataset isn't mandatory in the JSON. So, if you remove it or comment it out the activity should just keep the original name.

This is certainly true for copy activities.

Comment: Hi Paul! Thanks for your answer. This is not the results I observed. Filenames did change on copy.

Comment: @YuGagarin strange. There must be something else going off then. I have a ADF solution running in production copying file into ADL storage that retains file names. Could you please share the JSON of your datasets and activity in the question? Thanks

Comment: Is it just one file you copy to ADL or a few of them?

Comment: About 20 of them :-)

Comment: Here they are https://1drv.ms/u/s!AAV6e0kPEl4ojQQ . The catch is that when files are moved from local/on-prem file share to Azure Blob they do keep their names, but when they finally moved to Data Lake, names became garbaged by Azure to something like Data.0fdf76a8-5ef9-4624-83b3-f614a1d8b204

Comment: Looks like it is by design according to this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector#example-copy-data-from-azure-blob-to-azure-data-lake-store . "When fileName is not specified, Copy includes all files in the folderPath for input dataset.

When fileName is not specified for an output dataset, the name of the generated file would be in the following this format: Data..txt (for example: : Data.0a405f8a-93ff-4c6f-b3be-f69616f1df7a.txt" . It would make sense to preserve old filenames, but oh well.. Only options is a copy activity per file :(